# IronSource network are not setting live my ads on my Apps?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, ironsource

I integrated IronSource ads into my Unity Levelplay project and everything was running smoothly in demo mode. However, when they asked for my bank details to verify my account on the IronSource network, I provided them and was then told that all was complete. They requested the URL for my app on the Play Store, which I sent two months after finishing my project. However, they rejected my app with the following message:

> Thank you for your interest in partnering with ironSource.
> Following careful review, we found that your app doesn't match our current focus. Therefore, your account was not approved and your app can't go live on the ironSource Network.

I have not received any further information from them and they are not responding to my emails. Should I consider switching to Google AdMob for their better team support?